# Cannot run ANY shell scripts even when root

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

when trying to run a teamspeak server and a minecraft server on a newly rented VPS I ran into some big troubles. Whenever I try to run a shell script even when root it does not work.

One script: spigot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")
cd "$BINDIR"
java -Xms5G -Xmx7G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar spigot.jar
```

Error after trying to use this as root

```
root@vps23946:/home/user/minecraft# ./spigot.sh
-bash: ./spigot.sh: Permission denied
```

Error after trying to use this as user

```
user@vps23946:~/minecraft$ ./spigot.sh
-bash: ./spigot.sh: Permission denied
```

Results from ls -l

```
root@vps23946:/home/user/minecraft# ls -l
total 22616
drwxr-xr-x 16 user root     4096 Jun  6 22:39 backups
-rw-r--r--  1 user root        2 Jun  7 13:54 banned-ips.json
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      110 May 25 17:32 banned-ips.txt.converted
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      229 Jun  7 13:54 banned-players.json
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      267 May 25 17:32 banned-players.txt.converted
-rw-r--r--  1 user root     1474 Jun  7 13:54 bukkit.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      610 Jun  7 13:54 commands.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 user root     4096 Jun  6 19:56 crash-reports
drwxr-xr-x  2 user root     4096 Jun  7 13:54 C:\Users\Rory Finnegan\Desktop\Prep     server\backups
drwxr-xr-x  6 user root     4096 Jun  7 14:25 flat
-rw-r--r--  1 user root     2576 Apr  3 16:04 help.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 user root     4096 Jun  7 13:54 logs
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      415 Jun  7 13:54 ops.json
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      191 May 28 19:02 ops.txt.converted
-rw-r--r--  1 user root        0 Apr  3 16:05 permissions.yml
drwxr-xr-x 27 user root     4096 Jun  6 22:39 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      768 Jun  7 13:54 server.properties
-rw-r--r--  1 user root 23053543 May 30 15:48 spigot.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      122 Jun  7 13:36 spigot.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 user root     2749 Jun  7 13:54 spigot.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 user root     2404 Jun  7 14:07 usercache.json
-rw-r--r--  1 user root     1588 Apr  3 16:04 wepif.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      783 Jun  6 16:21 whitelist.json
-rw-r--r--  1 user root      250 May  3 19:31 white-list.txt.converted
drwxr-xr-x  7 user root     4096 Jun  7 14:25 world
drwxr-xr-x  6 user root     4096 Jun  7 14:25 world_nether
drwxr-xr-x  6 user root     4096 Jun  7 14:25 world_the_end
```

Second Script: ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
    #!/bin/sh

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=".:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

D1=$(readlink -f "$0")
D2=$(dirname "${D1}")
cd "${D2}"

if [ -e ts3server_linux_x86 ]; then
    if [ -z "`uname | grep Linux`" -o ! -z "`uname -m | grep 64`" ]; then
            echo "Do you have the right TS3 Server package for your system? You have:        `    uname` `uname -m`, not Linux i386."
    fi
    ./ts3server_linux_x86 $@
elif [ -e ts3server_linux_amd64 ]; then
    if [ -z "`uname | grep Linux`" -o -z "`uname -m | grep 64`" ]; then
            echo "Do you have the right TS3 Server package for your system? You have: `  uname` `uname -m`, not Linux x86_64."
    fi
    ./ts3server_linux_amd64 $@
elif [ -e ts3server_freebsd_x86 ]; then
    if [ ! -z "`uname | grep Linux`" -o ! -z "`uname -m | grep 64`" ]; then
@
```

With these I get the same errors.

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: make sure the script is executable `chmod a+x spigot.sh`

Comment: set the execute permission: `chmod +x myscript.sh`

Comment: You said the shell script is named `spigot.jar`. Isn't it actually `spigot.sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts and programs must be executable to be invoked by name. Either use `chmod` to add the executable permission to the file (`chmod a+x ./spigot.sh`) or invoke an executable interpreter and pass in the script, e.g. `/bin/sh ./spigot.sh`

Comment: This worked for my spigot.sh but the teamspeak.sh is still denying permissions after also applying this solution.

Comment: @user3718351: You ran `chmod +x teamspeak.sh` followed by `./teamspeak.sh`? Is the `#!` line correct?

Comment: There was another program that the script ran that was not executable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 chmod +x spigot.sh
```

and that will enable the script to be executed